# No JavaScript being detected on page (history.pushState)

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

I was following along with Jeffery Way's [history.pushState tutorial on Tuts+](https://tutsplus.com/lesson/history-pushstate/), however I'm not able to get his results.

Basically, here is my test page: http://leongaban.com/_tuts+/HTML5/

With the script at the bottom of the page, the URL is suppose to look like http://leongaban.com/_tuts+/HTML5/page however nothing happens, also in Chrome and Firefox the developer tools are telling me there is no JavaScript on the page?

My full markup (same as Jeffery's):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>History – pushState</title>

</head>

<body>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://d2o0t5hpnwv4c1.cloudfront.net/2086_get-good-with-php/preview.png" title="Rockable">Rockable</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://tutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/bestof/bestoftuts.jpg" title="Best">Best of Tuts</a></li>

        <li><a href="http://net.tutsplus.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/200x200.png" title="Advanced JS">Advanced JS</a></li>
    </ul>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        history.pushState(
            'Some data'
            'My Page Title'
            'page'
        );
    </script>

    </body>

    </html>


    <!--

    <script>
        history.go(-1); < Go back 1 page
        history.go(2); < Go forward 2 pages
        history.go(0); < Refresh current page
        history.forward(); < Forward 1 page
        history.back(); < Back 1 page
    </script>

    -->
```

Comment: It does not look like you are loading a JavaScript file.

Comment: My console is showing there is an error in your code "missing ) after argument list/_tuts+/HTML5/:23"

Comment: You need commas after each parameter to `pushState`.

Comment: I am curious, was the negative down votes on this because of me missing the commas in the Javascript? Or because of outbound links? Please I'd like to know for next time...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass commas into that function, to seperate the variables you are passing to pushState

```
 history.pushState(
            'Some data',
            'My Page Title',
            'page'
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

You need commas! I get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string /_tuts+/HTML5/:31`

```
history.pushState(
    'Some data',
    'My Page Title',
    'page'
);
```

Comment: thanks! Can't believe I forgot that, sigh... too bad I can only choose one answer